# Would you say "pull the ball open to make all the shapes come out"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [pull](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pull_1?q=pull) [intransitive, transitive] to take hold of something and use
>   force in order to move it or try to move it towards yourself
>
> You push and I'll pull.
>
> Don't pull so hard or the handle will come off.
>
> He got hold of the end and pulled.
>
> pull on something I pulled on the rope to see if it was secure.
>
> pull at something He pulled at her coat sleeve.
>
> pull something Stop pulling her hair!
>
> She pulled the cord and the parachute opened.
>
> pull somebody/something + adv./prep. She pulled him gently towards
>   her.
>
> He smiled and pulled her closer.
>
> **pull something + adj**. Pull the door shut.
>
> She pulled the straps tight.

[image]

I have a ball which has many holes of different shapes in it (look at the above picture). Children will learn shapes buy putting the right shapes into the right holes. When all the shapes got inside the ball, we've got to "**pull the ball open to make all the shapes come out**" so that the children can play again.

**Note**: there are 2 handles at the opposite positions. You can pull the handles out by using your both hands and the ball separated the 2 halves apart.

Comment: I know that ball! My boys played with it for years. I might write it the way you did, or I might write "open the ball by the handles to get the shapes out again".

Comment: *Pull the ball **apart**.*